# Using Blade/Mustache templating mixing Laravel and Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I'm trying to build an application with both **Laravel** and **VueJs** but I'm stuck at one point.

Is it possible to use VueJs mustache templating (which is `{{exemple}}` ) without launching a Laravel error since laravel used it too like `{{$exemple}}`?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs as I'm not sure if the `@{{ example }}` syntax might help?

Comment: Ho god! Thank you! You just showed me I could escape blade templating. Marvelous! Answer it with `@{{ exemple }}` and I'll accept your answer :).

Comment: No problem, there you go :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you can do what you're after using the `@{{ example }}` syntax that Blade allows us to use when using a JS framework inside Laravel.

Hope this helps! :)