# Conflict between ( Laravel ) Blade template engine and AMP Mustache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, amp-html, mustache

Mustache template Engine is conflicting with Blade.

I am working on a php Laravelv 6.0 project which uses Blade as a template engine and i implement some AMP pages.
When i use **AMP mustache** template inside a blade file, conflicts and displays the error below:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined*

More info to this github issue:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/29036

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fix for a similar bug and found it here -> [Using Blade/Mustache templating mixing Laravel and Vue.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956220/using-blade-mustache-templating-mixing-laravel-and-vue-js) ...

add `@` before {{value}}

```
<template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-custom">
      <div>@{{category}}</div>
</template>
```